# codebuild errors while trying to login to AWS cross-account using a shell script inside codebuild buildspec

Tags: json, bash, amazon-web-services, shell, aws-codebuild

I'm using a shell script inside codebuild buildspec on **Account A** to login into **Account B** and seeing te below error, but when use the commands directly in buildspec file I'm able to login successfully into **Account B**
**Error Details**

```
jq: error: Could not open file login.json: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file login.json: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file login.json: No such file or directory
An HTTP Client raised an unhandled exception: Invalid header value b'\r\r\r'
```

**Auth.sh**

```
echo $1 
 roleArn=$1
 aws sts assume-role --role-arn $roleArn --role-session-name testx > login.json
 GetAccess=$(jq '.Credentials.AccessKeyId' login.json)
 Access=$(echo "$GetAccess" | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')
 GetSecret=$(jq '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey' login.json)
 secret=$(echo "$GetSecret" | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')
 GetTOken=$(jq '.Credentials.SessionToken' login.json)
 token=$(echo "$GetTOken" | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')
 export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$Access
 export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$secret
 export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$token
 aws s3 ls
```

**buildspec.yam**

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - ls
  build:
    commands:
     - aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/auth.sh auth.sh
     - chmod a+x auth.sh
     - ./auth.sh "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/roleToLogin"
     - ls
     - aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/roleToLogin"  --role-session-name testx > login.json
     - GetAccess=$(jq '.Credentials.AccessKeyId' login.json)
     - Access=$(echo "$GetAccess" | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')
     - GetSecret=$(jq '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey' login.json)
     - secret=$(echo "$GetSecret" | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')
     - GetTOken=$(jq '.Credentials.SessionToken' login.json)
     - token=$(echo "$GetTOken" | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')
     - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$Access
     - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$secret
     - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$token
     - rm -f login.json
     - aws s3 ls
     
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo test
```

[image]
I'm I missing something here?

Comment: Can you show the buildspec file that  you use? Also which CB image are you using?

Comment: @Marcin Updated question with the requested details

Comment: Thanks. So you are running the code twice. First in `./auth.sh "roleToLogin"` and then the same code again?

Comment: @Marcin No just for the reference/testing purpose I've included the second set of login command in the buildspec but the eventual goal is to use auth.sh

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other errors from your CB? Did you enable cloudwatch logs for the builds?

Comment: @Marcin I don't see any other errors other than the above-mentioned errors, which is jq couldn't open login.json file

Comment: @Marcin When I use the ls command it doesn't work inside the auth.sh script

Comment: In the code posted there is also some `cred.json`, so its confusing what is this file? But code in itself is correct. It should not fail.

Comment: @Marcin Is there anything with file permission, since I'm creating this file auth.sh file on windows machine?

Comment: Oh. Could be. Windows can have different new line characters then linux. Maybe have to look into that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228607/discussion-between-chris-and-marcin).

Comment: Answer modified and un-deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and chat discussion.

The issue was due to using Windows to create the `auth.sh`. Windows was adding some **extra white characters** to it, resulting in the error.

Using `dos2unix` tool to **convert** windows file format to linux solved the problem.

Comment: I'm able to login with the second set of commands(outside of shell script) using the same rolearn

Comment: @chris Please double check. `--role-arn roleToLogin` is invalid for the current CLI. It must be `--role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/roleToLogin`.

Comment: and also If I use the cat  login.json I'm able to see the temporary creds and  token generated

Comment: @chris Maybe you are checking other script, not the one in the question. I don't see how it could work with just a role name `--role-arn roleToLogin`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I'm passing the roleToLogin into the shell script as the format you provided

Comment: @chris I see. That's correct. I will try to try to look more why it fails. If can't find anything I will remove the answer.